# Searching a hook which triggers when deleting a post to get all comments

Tags: hooks

When deleting a post, all comments associated with this post get the status "post-trashed". I'm searching a hook for this event.

Tried these one without success:
`comment_approved_to_post-trashed
comment_approved_to_trash`

Answer (score 2):

There are few other hooks to manipulated the trashed comment.

1. 'save_post': called after post is saved. You can check status of the post and manipulate its comment accordingly.
2. 'trashed_comment': called after comment is moved to trash status.
3. 'transition_comment_status': called whenever comment status is changed.

There are probably few others too. But, it depends what you want to do with the trashed comments.

Comment: the second hook won't trigger when deleting a post, because the comment is actually not trashed (not visisble in the trash or anywhere else), it only gets the status "post-trashed" in the database. I will try it with the third hook. Which parameters will I get with that hook? I need at least the comment_ID and the old+new status.

Comment: Found it: wp_transition_comment_status( $new_status, $old_status, $comment )

Answer (score 1):

Sadly your hook didn't trigger when deleting a post. But I just looked into the wordpress code and found the right hook:

`* @uses do_action() on 'trashed_post_comments' after trashing`

in the function

`wp_trash_post_comments()`

And then just add the action like that:

```
add_action('trashed_post_comments', 'sp_trashed_post_comments', 10, 2);
...
function sp_trashed_post_comments($postID, $statuses) {
    $commentIDs = array_keys($statuses);
    print_r($commentIDs); // echoes all commentIDs associated with the deleted post
}
```